# Newer versions, listed in 'Latest', may not be mutually compatiable in flutter

Tags: flutter

E:\New folder (2)\xolo>flutter pub outdated
Showing outdated packages.
[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name  Current  Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest

direct dependencies: all up-to-date.

transitive dependencies:
async         *2.6.1   *2.6.1      *2.6.1      2.7.0
charcode      *1.2.0   *1.2.0      *1.2.0      1.3.1
meta          *1.3.0   *1.3.0      *1.3.0      1.4.0
rxdart        *0.26.0  *0.26.0     *0.26.0     0.27.1

transitive dev_dependencies:
test_api      *0.3.0   *0.3.0      *0.3.0      0.4.1
You are already using the newest resolvable versions listed in the 'Resolvable' column.
Newer versions, listed in 'Latest', may not be mutually compatible.

Comment: Please add more details on the specific problem you are facing, also see [How to ask a good StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: have you found a solution?